# How to reverse a number as an integer and not as a string?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I came across a question "How can one reverse a number as an integer and not as a string?" Could anyone please help me to find out the answer? Reversal should reverse the decimal digits of the number, i.e. use base 10.

Comment: If you mean reverse the digits, then you are basically reversing a string - convert to string, reverse, convert back...

Comment: I think it looks more like Project Euler. Problem number 4, to be exact :p

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This should do it:

```
int n = 12345;
int left = n;
int rev = 0;
while(Convert.ToBoolean(left)) // instead of left>0 , to reverse signed numbers as well
{
   int r = left % 10;   
   rev = rev * 10 + r;
   left = left / 10;  //left = Math.floor(left / 10); 
}

Console.WriteLine(rev);
```

Comment: Thanks so much , but I think this will not work when given number has 0 at end. just like 40

Comment: where did you declare *r* inside while loop?

Comment: just a thought,I know its no mentioned specifically for negative numbers but to support reverse negative number, you have to check left !=0 in while loop otherwise it will not go in when condition is left >0.

Comment: @jerjer Depends on what you want. If it is *digits* you want then the leading zero will be lost, and reversing it again will obviously also drop the leading zero. However, if you are interested in the digits: reverse the frickin' string! A digit is nothing more than a *character representation* of a number *encoded in base 10* after all. And as there are precious few applications in math where this kind of reversal makes *any sense* you could argue that string reversal should always be applied.

Comment: it is not working with negative number.

If you change it as below it will 

while (Convert.ToBoolean(left))
            {
                var r = left % 10;
                rev = rev * 10 + r;
                left = left / 10;  //left = Math.floor(left / 10); 
            }

Answer (score 60):

Something like this?

```
public int ReverseInt(int num)
{
    int result=0;
    while (num>0) 
    {
       result = result*10 + num%10;
       num /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

As a hackish one-liner (update: used Benjamin's comment to shorten it):

```
num.ToString().Reverse().Aggregate(0, (b, x) => 10 * b + x - '0');
```

A speedier one-and-a-quarter-liner:

```
public static int ReverseOneLiner(int num)
{
    for (int result=0;; result = result * 10 + num % 10, num /= 10) if(num==0) return result;
    return 42;
}
```

It's not a one-liner because I had to include `return 42;`. The C# compiler wouldn't let me compile because it thought that no code path returned a value.

P.S. If you write code like this and a co-worker catches it, you deserve everything he/she does to you. Be warned!

EDIT: I wondered about how much slower the LINQ one-liner is, so I used the following benchmark code:

```
public static void Bench(Func<int,int> myFunc, int repeat)
{
    var R = new System.Random();
    var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
    {
        var ignore = myFunc(R.Next());
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Operation took {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Result (10^6 random numbers in positive int32 range):

```
While loop version:
Operation took 279ms

Linq aggregate:
Operation took 984ms
```

Comment: Although the one-liner is very inefficient.

Comment: Of course, that's why I called it hackish. It's more of a curiosity.

Comment: ToCharArray() is redundant and you could do the char to int conversion from your select in the aggregate as well - saves horizontal space. :) See my sample below for the string-only version.

Comment: @cfern you missed a little check if the number is negative... My teacher back in college would have a field day with this... :-P

Comment: Oops. That's what happen if you code something within 60 seconds. I wonder how to define the reverse of a negative number. Rev (-1234) = -4321?

Comment: interesting fact - 42 in binary is 101010 ;)

Comment: @Benjamin: thanks for the tip! Intellisense didn't popup any LINQ for a string as char array, even though it's there. Learned something new today :). I've edited the one-liner.

Comment: Probably not a big deal, but shouldn't you use the same numbers for both functions? And maybe generate the numbers before you start the timer?

Comment: Pre-generating the numbers yields a fairer comparison. I've written this bench in a hurry, so I didn't do it as statistically nice as possible. I do think that, in this case, the sheer amount of numbers that go into benchmark averages out the differences from experiment to experiment.

Comment: Thanks cfern...but first method is not working when the number end with 0. For example when I give input 40 this method returning 4.

Comment: That sounds right to me. Because the algorithm I posted calculates with integers, 04 is returned as the number 4. If you wish to keep trailing zeroes, you should work with the number as a string. Something like `return new String(num.ToString().Reverse().ToArray());`, where num is the (integer) input.

Comment: @cfern: if you want to reverse the negative number first you should to do convert it to absolute value and reverse it... after reverse you are just mulitiply -1 with the result.
step 1: -4321 convert in absolute value to 4321
step 2: then 4321 reverse to 1234
step 3: and last 1234 * (-1)

Answer (score 4):

```
using System; 

public class DoWhileDemo {   
  public static void Main() { 
    int num; 
    int nextdigit; 

    num = 198; 

    Console.WriteLine("Number: " + num); 

    Console.Write("Number in reverse order: "); 

    do { 
      nextdigit = num % 10; 
      Console.Write(nextdigit); 
      num = num / 10; 
    } while(num > 0); 

    Console.WriteLine(); 
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

multiply it by -1? precise your question please...

Comment: Actually as I mentioned in the question line...I came across this question in a website, where they have published multiple interview question. So I am also confused with the question line.

Answer (score 4):

Yay! A bling way. (No, really. I hope that this is more a "How would I do..." question and not something you really need in production)

```
public int Reverse(int number) {
  return int.Parse(number.ToString().Reverse().Aggregate("", (s,c) => s+c));
}
```

Comment: ... if it wasn't for "not as a string" directly as a title.

Answer (score 3):

Check below simple and easy -

```
public int reverseNumber(int Number)
{
  int ReverseNumber = 0;
  while(Number > 0)
  {
    ReverseNumber = (ReverseNumber * 10) + (Number % 10);
    Number = Number / 10;
  }
  return ReverseNumber;
}
```

**Reference :** [Reverse number program in c#](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/03/reverse-number-program-in-c.html)

Answer (score 3):

Old thread, but I did not see this variation:

```
        int rev(int n) {
            string str = new String(n.ToString().Reverse().ToArray());
            return int.Parse(str);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Since the computer thinks in hexadecimal in any case, it is necessary for you to tokenise the number into Arabic format, which is semantically identical to the conversion to string.

Comment: @Alex: to be more precise computer works with bits and hexadecimal is an exact multiple (ie: groups of 4 bits for each hexadecimal digit). But it still can do maths however as showed above.

Answer (score 1):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Reverse a int using its sting representation.
    /// </summary>
    private int ReverseNumber(int value)
    {
        string textValue = value.ToString().TrimStart('-');

        char[] valueChars = textValue.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(valueChars);
        string reversedValue = new string(valueChars);
        int reversedInt = int.Parse(reversedValue);

        if (value < 0)
           reversedInt *= -1;

        return reversedInt;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the following solution. But how about when n is negative?

Lets say n = -123456

Here is a tweak I added to it to handle negative numbers, with that assumption it will threat negative numbs the same way.

```
        int reverse = 0;
        bool isNegative = false;

        if (n < 0)
            isNegative = true;

        n = Math.Abs(n);
        while (n > 0)
        {
            int rem = n % 10;
            reverse = (reverse * 10) + rem;
            n = n / 10;
        }

        if (isNegative)
            reverse = reverse * (-1);

        return reverse;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public int ReverseNumber(int number)
        {
            int result = 0;

            while (number > 0)
            {
                int remainder = number % 10; // Get the last digit of the number
                result = (result * 10) + remainder; // Append the last digit to the result in reverse order
                number /= 10; // Remove the last digit from the number
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

the shortest solution:

```
        int reverse=0;
        int number = 21;

        while (number > 0)
        {
            reverse = number % 10;
            Console.Write(reverse);
            number = number / 10;  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per  **Pritam Karmakar** comment ,
Yes this will not work when given number has 0 at end.
If you pass number as 150 it will return 51 not 051.
so i had write code to display number in Reverse order as per user input please check this.

```
int reverseNum = 0, reminder, num;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Number to Reverse:");
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num);
        bool isZero = false;
        int cnt=0;
        while (num > 0)
        {
            reminder = num % 10;
            reverseNum = (reverseNum * 10) + reminder;
            num = num / 10;
            if (reverseNum == 0)
                isZero = true;                
            cnt++;
        }
        if (isZero)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reverseNum.ToString().PadLeft(cnt, '0'));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reverseNum);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int reversed = Reverse(-7360);
    }

    public static int Reverse(int number, int left = 0, int right = 0)
    {
        if (number == 0) return left + right;
        return Reverse(number / 10, left * 10 + right * 10, number % 10);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter number");
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(ReverseLoop(number));
        Console.WriteLine(ReverseRecursive(number));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static int ReverseRecursive(int number)
    {
        int remainder = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
        if (number < 1)
            return remainder;
        return ReverseRecursive(number) + remainder * Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(10, number.ToString().Length));
    }

    public static int ReverseLoop(int number)
    {
        int reversed = 0;
        while (number > 0)
        {
            reversed = reversed * 10 + (number % 10);
            number = number / 10;
        }
        return reversed;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution suggested by **@jerjer** and **@cfern** is perfect but It will not work for **negative int number** like **-1234507**.

**Solution** : If number is negative int then multiply by -1 after that call your method ReverseInt(-1234507)

```
    int number = -1234507;
    **number = number > 0 ? number : (number * -1);**

    int reverseNumber = 0;

    while(number > 0){
        reverseNumber = (reverseNumber * 10) +  (number % 10) ;
        number = number / 10;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(reverseNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
Convert.ToInt32(new string(num.ToString().Reverse().ToArray()));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int sum = 0; int remainder = 0;
        int n = 123;
        for (int i = n; i > 0; i = i / 10)
        {
            remainder = i % 10;
            sum = (sum * 10) + remainder;
        }
Console.WriteLine(sum);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score -1):

a new one:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int i = 234;
        int j = -123;
        Console.WriteLine(reverse(i));
        Console.WriteLine(reverse(j));
    }

    static int reverse(int i)
    {
        int sign = i / Math.Abs(i);
        var abs = string.Concat(Math.Abs(i).ToString().Reverse());
        return int.Parse(abs) * sign;
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/VGJJFf

Answer (score -2):

```
int x = 9876543;
char[] arr = x.ToString().ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(arr);
Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(new string(arr)));
```