# More efficient algorithm for printing numbers that are palindromic and their power to 2 are palindromic too

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am looking for more efficient algorithm for printing numbers that are palindromic (for example 1001) and their power to 2 (1001 * 1001 = 1002001) are palindromic too. In my algorithm I think I make unnecessary checks to determine if number is palindromic. How can I improve it?

In [1000,9999] range I found this kind of 3 numbers: 1001, 1111 and 2002.

This is my algorithm:

```
for (int i = n; i <= m; i++)
{
    if (checkIfPalindromic(i.ToString()))
    {
        if (checkIfPalindromic((i * i).ToString()))
             Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

this is my method to determine if number is palindromic:

```
static bool checkIfPalindromic(string A)
{
    int n = A.Length - 1;
    int i = 0;
    bool IsPalindromic = true;

    while (i < (n - i))
    {
        if (A[i] != A[n - i])
        {
            IsPalindromic = false;
            break;
        }

        i++;
    }

    return IsPalindromic;
}
```

Comment: An obvious optimisation is to replace `IsPalindromic = false; break` with `return false;`. You don't need to continue looping once you've determined that the string is not a palindrome.

Comment: right, thank you..

Comment: Check out my new answer! it is two time faster.

Comment: @ Hussein Golshani I will,

Comment: @maxim1000's answer is best. Iterate through palindromes not through integers. E.g., you will cycle through all 10^5 integers of length 10 that start 12345, of which only one (the one ending 54321) is a palindrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking very number for "palindromness", it may be better to iterate through palindromes only. For that just iterate over the first halves of the number and then compose palindrome from it.

```
for(int half=10;half<=99;++half)
{
    const int candidate=half*100+Reverse(half);//may need modification for odd number of digits
    if(IsPalindrome(candidate*candidate))
        Output(candidate);
}
```

This will make your program `O(sqrt(m))` instead of `O(m)`, which will probably beat all improvements of constant factors.

Answer (score 1):

What you have already seems fairly efficient

Scale is checking 1,000,000 integers

**Note** : i use longs

**Disclaimer** : I must admit these results are a little sketchy, ive added more scaling so you can see

**Results**

```
Mode            : Release
Test Framework  : .Net 4.7.1
Benchmarks runs : 10 times (averaged)

Scale : 1,000
Name     |  Average |  Fastest | StDv |  Cycles | Pass |    Gain
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Mine2    | 0.107 ms | 0.102 ms | 0.01 | 358,770 | Yes  |  5.83 %
Original | 0.114 ms | 0.098 ms | 0.05 | 361,810 | Base |  0.00 %
Mine     | 0.120 ms | 0.100 ms | 0.03 | 399,935 | Yes  | -5.36 %


Scale : 10,000
Name     |  Average |  Fastest | StDv |    Cycles | Pass |    Gain
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Mine2    | 1.042 ms | 0.944 ms | 0.17 | 3,526,050 | Yes  | 11.69 %
Mine     | 1.073 ms | 0.936 ms | 0.19 | 3,633,369 | Yes  |  9.06 %
Original | 1.180 ms | 0.920 ms | 0.29 | 3,964,418 | Base |  0.00 %


Scale : 100,000
Name     |   Average |  Fastest | StDv |     Cycles | Pass |   Gain
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Mine2    | 10.406 ms | 9.502 ms | 0.91 | 35,341,208 | Yes  | 6.59 %
Mine     | 10.479 ms | 9.332 ms | 1.09 | 35,592,718 | Yes  | 5.93 %
Original | 11.140 ms | 9.272 ms | 1.72 | 37,624,494 | Base | 0.00 %


Scale : 1,000,000
Name     |    Average |    Fastest | StDv |      Cycles | Pass |    Gain
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Original | 106.271 ms | 101.662 ms | 3.61 | 360,996,200 | Base |  0.00 %
Mine     | 107.559 ms | 102.695 ms | 5.35 | 365,525,239 | Yes  | -1.21 %
Mine2    | 108.757 ms | 104.530 ms | 4.81 | 368,939,992 | Yes  | -2.34 %

Mode            : Release
Test Framework  : .Net Core 2.0
Benchmarks runs : 10 times (averaged)

Scale : 1,000,000
Name     |    Average |   Fastest |  StDv |      Cycles | Pass |    Gain
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mine2    |  95.054 ms | 87.144 ms |  8.45 | 322,650,489 | Yes  | 10.54 %
Mine     |  95.849 ms | 89.971 ms |  5.38 | 325,315,589 | Yes  |  9.79 %
Original | 106.251 ms | 84.833 ms | 17.97 | 350,106,144 | Base |  0.00 %
```

**Given**

```
protected override List<int> InternalRun()
{
   var results = new List<int>();
   for (var i = 0; i <= Input; i++)
      if (checkIfPalindromic(i) && checkIfPalindromic(i * (long)i))
            results.Add(i);             

   return results;
}
```

**Mine1**

```
private static unsafe bool checkIfPalindromic(long value)
{
   var str = value.ToString();
   fixed (char* pStr = str)
   {
      for (char* p = pStr, p2 = pStr + str.Length - 1; p < p2;)
         if (*p++ != *p2--)
            return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

**Mine2**

```
private static bool checkIfPalindromic(long value)
{
   var str = value.ToString();
   var n = str.Length - 1;

   for (var i = 0; i < n - i; i++)
      if (str[i] != str[n - i])
         return false;

   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More optimistic way is to use `int` instead of `string`. this algorithm is about two time faster:

```
static int[] pow10 = { 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000 };

static bool checkIfPalindromic(int A)
{
    int n = 1;
    int i = A;
    if (i >= 100000000) { n += 8; i /= 100000000; }
    if (i >= 10000) { n += 4; i /= 10000; }
    if (i >= 100) { n += 2; i /= 100; }
    if (i >= 10) { n++; }


    int num = A / pow10[(n+1) / 2];
    for (; num % 10 == 0;)
        num /= 10;

    int reversedNum = 0;
    for (int input = A % pow10[ n / 2]; input != 0; input /= 10)
        reversedNum = reversedNum * 10 + input % 10;

    return num == reversedNum;
}
```

Usage:

```
for (int i = n; i <= m; i++)
    if (checkIfPalindromic(i) && checkIfPalindromic(i * i))
             Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Benchmark:

```
Bemchmark in range of [1000, 99999999]  on Core2Duo CPU:

This algorithm: 12261ms
Your algorithm: 24181ms

Palindromic Numbers:
1001
1111
2002
10001
10101
10201
11011
11111
11211
20002
20102
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can use Linq to simplify your code

sample:-

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n = 1000, m = 9999;
    for (int i = n; i <= m; i++)
    {
       if (CheckIfNoAndPowerPalindromic(i))
       {
           Console.WriteLine(i);
       }
    }
}

private static bool CheckIfNoAndPowerPalindromic(int number)
{
   string numberString = number.ToString();
   string numberSquareString = (number * number).ToString();

   return (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(numberString.ToCharArray(), numberString.ToCharArray().Reverse()) && 
           Enumerable.SequenceEqual(numberSquareString.ToCharArray(), numberSquareString.ToCharArray().Reverse()));
}

output:-
1001
1111 
2002.
```

Comment: @A.M how did you came to that conclusion? please explain?

Comment: Did you compare it with after optimised suggested by @matthew

Comment: My Timediff = 0175361 ur 
Timediff = 0031125 I think you are correct

Answer (score 0):

Loop up to len/2 as follow:

```
static bool checkIfPalindromic(string A)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < A.Length / 2; i++)
        if (A[i] != A[A.Length - i - 1])
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: @A.M What makes you think that?

Comment: I compared them and found difference in execution time

Answer (score 0):

We can get an interesting optimisation by changing the palindromic checking method and using a **direct integer reversing method** instead of converting first to a string then looping in the string.

I used the method in the accepted answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040702/how-to-reverse-a-number-as-an-integer-and-not-as-a-string):

```
static int reverse(int n)
{
   int left = n;
   int rev = 0;
   int r = 0;
   while (left > 0)
   {
      r = left % 10;
      rev = rev * 10 + r;
      left = left / 10; 
   }
   return rev;
}
```

I also used the StopWatch from `System.Diagnostics` to measure the elapsed time.

My function to check if a number is a palindromic number is:

```
static bool IsPalindromicNumber(int number)
{
   return reverse(number) == number;
}
```

For **n value of 1000** and for different values of m I get the following results for the elapsed time in milliseconds:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| m        | original        | mine       | optimisation|
---------------------------------------------------------
|9999      |6.3855           |4.2171      | -33.95%     |
---------------------------------------------------------
|99999     |71.3961          |42.3399     | -40.69%     |
--------------------------------------------------------- 
|999999    |524.4921         |342.8899    | -34.62%     |
---------------------------------------------------------
|9999999   |7016.4050        |4565.4563   | -34.93%     |   
---------------------------------------------------------
|99999999  |71319.658        |49837.5632  | -30.12%     |   
---------------------------------------------------------
```

The measured values are an indicative and not absolute because from one run of the program to another they are different but the pattern stays the same and the second approach appears always faster.

To measure using the StopWatch:

**With your method:**

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
for (int i = n; i <= m; i++)
{
   if (checkIfPalindromic(i.ToString()))
   {
      if (checkIfPalindromic((i * i).ToString()))
         Console.WriteLine(i);
   }
}
stopWatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("First approach: Elapsed time..." + stopWatch.Elapsed + " which is " + stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " miliseconds");
```

I used of course exact same approach with my changes:

**With my method:**

```
Stopwatch stopWatch2 = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch2.Start();
for (int i = n; i <= m; i++)
{
   if (IsPalindromicNumber(i) && IsPalindromicNumber(i*i))
   {
      Console.WriteLine(i);
   }
}

stopWatch2.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Second approach: Elapsed time..." + stopWatch2.Elapsed + " which is " + stopWatch2.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " miliseconds");
```